# what ratio should we keep between kafka broker and zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have read that if we have 4 kafka cluster why do we need 5 ZK than. This is said that it is the most optimistic way to make kafka clusters but I didn't get this point.

please explain me this. I have tried 3 brokers with 3 ZK so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka uses ZK for coordination of brokers, election of controller, etc. [This post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-role-of-Zookeeper-in-Kafka-What-benefits-will-I-miss-out-on-if-I-don%E2%80%99t-use-Zookeeper-and-Kafka-together) describes this in great details.  Usually, ZK is operated as cluster of instances with odd number of instances to be able to make decision based on quorum, so usual size is 3, 5, 7, ...

For that size of Kafka cluster, 3 ZKs should be enough, although it may depend on the load to ZK, and some other factors